# Would this question about wheelies on scooters be on-topic on Engineering?

Tags: support

Would this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/681885/295887 about wheelies on scooters be on-topic on Engineering? Someone commented that it wasn't about physics, and I kind of see his point.

Comment: It really isn't an engineering question. It is either asking about skill/experience or the actual free body diagram of what is happening. Neither of those is an engineering question.